# comboboxlist move files wont move

Tags: c#, winforms

I need some assistance with moving some files using a combolistcheck box. I have a method that populates each combo box. From there I have a button that controls which box (folder) to move the file too (depending on what items are checked). I have seen a few tutorials about making lists and moving items from one list to another but there seems to be something im missing when it comes to files. Below is the code I am using.

[image: Main Form]

[Populate checklistbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqrtF.png)

[Move files based on checked items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKkA0.png)

```
private void Populatetocheck()
    {

        List<string> Tobechecked = new List<string>();
        string[] tobedirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path.Text, "1-TO BE CHECKED", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (string tobe in tobedirs)
        {
            string searchfolder = tobe;

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(searchfolder);
            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*");
            string str = "";

            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                Tobechecked.Add(file.Name);
                //MessageBox.Show(file.Name);
            }
        }

        tocheck.DataSource = Tobechecked;
        tocheck.DisplayMember = Name;
    }


private void moveright_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string scopecheckfolder = path.Text;
        string tocheckfolder = path.Text + @"\1-TO BE CHECKED\";
        string checkedfolder = path.Text + @"\2-CHECKED\";
        string backcheckfolder = path.Text + @"\3-BACK CHECKED AND SCRUBBED\";
        string finalizefolder = path.Text + @"\4-TO BE FINALIZED\";
        string issuefolder = path.Text + @"\5-READY TO ISSUE\";


        foreach (object checkprint in tocheck.CheckedItems) //moves files from to check to checked folder
                                                            //.OfType<object>().ToList()

        {
            System.IO.File.Move(Convert.ToString(checkprint), checkedfolder);
            Populatecheck();
        }
    }
```

Comment: We don't do images of code here.  Post it as text.

Comment: sorry im struggling getting it to post. its my 1st time.

Comment: Do not worry if the code is not formatted very well. We can help you to fix the formatting, but the important thing is that you paste the code used and not a link to an image.

Comment: HA! took me a while but I think i got it. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Quick glance, it looks like you are losing the file path of the file with `Tobechecked.Add(file.Name);`.  Without the path, your program assumes the file is in the same directory as the executable, which it isn't.  So nothing moves.

Comment: Perfect! you guys answered my question. Thank you so much! Ill post my final code below

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments I just needed to add the path of the file since it was lost in the initial build of the check box list.

```
foreach (object checkprint in tocheck.CheckedItems) //moves files from to check to checked folder
                                                            //.OfType<object>().ToList()

        {
            //MessageBox.Show(path.Text + @"\1-TO BE CHECKED\" + checkprint + ",   " + path.Text + @"\2-CHECKED");

            string Filelocation = Path.Combine(path.Text + @"\1-TO BE CHECKED\" + checkprint);
            string newFilelocation = Path.Combine(path.Text + @"\2-CHECKED\" + checkprint);

            System.IO.File.Move(Filelocation, newFilelocation);
            Populatecheck();
            Populatetocheck();
        }
```